# Is immutable.js interchangeable with redis on a server?

Tags: javascript, database, data-structures, redis, immutable.js

Immutable.js states (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

> Immutable.js provides many Persistent Immutable data structures including: List, >Stack, Map, OrderedMap, Set, OrderedSet and Record.
>
> These data structures are highly efficient on modern JavaScript VMs by using >structural sharing via hash maps tries and vector tries as popularized by Clojure >and Scala, minimizing the need to copy or cache data.

Redis states (https://redis.io/)

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker. It supports data structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with radius queries. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU eviction, transactions and different levels of on-disk persistence, and provides high availability via Redis Sentinel and automatic partitioning with Redis Cluster.

Similar language shared in their descriptions lends me to think I could use Immutable.js as a "light" Redis solution or Redis as a "heavy" Immutable.js solution to track my multiplayer's game state (all active games state and players state).

- What are some key differences between these?
- When should someone select immutable.js over redis?
- When should someone select redis over immutable.js?

At present I cannot find a comparison of these two libraries (when I search Google or Stack Overflow), which makes me believe my assumption (that they can be used in place of each other at times) is woefully inaccurate, but I can find nothing to confirm or deny that.

I am not wondering if they can be used together (unless it is in a context of how they are different and compliment each other). I recognize Immutable.js is focused on handling structures that are Immutable, while Redis does not seem to be focused on that, but that still begs the question, can't I just stick with Immutable.js?

Here is my hang up... both provide data structures in memory. If I don't care about persistence, why should I care which I choose?

To be be clear the context is on a server not browser and if the server resets I don't want server state to persist (outside what is stored in mongoldb).

Comment: Absolutly not. Redis a database while Immutable is js library.

Comment: The only language that is similar in the two descriptions is *data structure*. Hell, everything is just works with data structures!

Comment: I get Redis is a database, but why should I want to use it to store application state over Immutable.js? I'm not sure why someone decided this was a bad question.

Comment: Because Immutable does not actually store anything on a disk? It does not provide persistency across application restarts.

Comment: I already clarified I don't need persistence. What other reasons should I chose redid to track server state?

Comment: I have the same question... I'm building an application running on k8s using nodejs, inside my application, I have some heavy caches, if I build it within my application, I need to handle the sychronization of caches across multiple pods... any pod may receive the change and then rebuild the data model and persist in db, and notify other pods to invalidate their caches and force a reload to refresh the cache to the latest state... however, this "notify other pods to invalidate cache" is easier said than done, considering the network failure, delay and etc, one need lots effort to realize this.

Comment: So, my idea is to split the responsibility of handling data model change to a separate service/pod, which will receive, process, and persist the change, and in addition, it will build the cached object in an Immutable way, and sync it to redis, while all existing app pods will simply retrieve and re-create these immutable cached objects from redis in their own pod, we can even leverage the redis to notify the change and trigger an automatic reload of cached objects (still immutables). Appreciate if anybody can comment on this and share experience if you have done so. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Immutable.js will hold your data structures on the client side and will be wiped whenever the user's browser memory is cleared, i.e when they close the browser.

Redis is an in-memory database for your server that will be able to do very quick lookups and send that data to your clients. You can use redis in lieu of a database, however it's usually a good idea to have a database as backup as redis memory is quite volatile.

They are both used to solve very different problems, for your case it sounds like all you need is immutable.js

If you needed your application to have save states you would then set up a way to send your immutable.js data structures to your server to be stored in a redis database.

Comment: Close the browser? Navigating to another page suffices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aaronw. I can use Immutable.js server side to track server state as well... To the best of my knowledge... So browser state seems irrelevant to my question. Regardless, even if my server reset that would be okay since I am just tracking games and players online. (usernames will be stored in mongoldb).  Maybe I need to clarify the question is in reference to the server.